# Salvar informações do usuário no Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, autenticação, firebase, realtime-database

Conforme a [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#obter_o_perfil_de_um_usuario) diz, não se deve usar o `getUid()` do usuário para autenticar usuários no backend server; ao invés disso, usar o `getToken()`. Entretanto, vejo muito código por aí usando este atributo para salvar coisas específicas de um usuário, por exemplo, uma lista de tarefas do usuário X.
O que devo usar de fato?

Comment: Acho que a recomendação do Firebase é evitar atrelar a autenticação do usuário ao id (que é imutável) ao contrário do token (que pode ser invalidado a qualquer momento). Mas você pode continuar usando o id para referenciar dados relacionados ao usuário sem problemas, só não use para controlar a sessão do usuário.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, @Wakin!

Answer (score 1):

A recomendação do Firebase é como a recomendação de de qualquer outra linguagem: É recomendável, mas não é obrigatório. O que acontece, é que na verdade, usar token é uma recomendação de segurança. Pois, por natureza um `token` é variável, sendo assim ele pode ser validade diversas vezes por variar a cada seção. Já o `uuid` é como se fosse a PRIMARY KEY de um banco relacional